# Get currency from Asset object in Apex

Tags: apex, multi-currency, currency, asset

How do I **get the currency in which asset price is stored**?

Can I write something like `asset.currency` in Apex?

I'm creating a package **for org with multiple currencies**, and I need to convert the asset price to one currency -- that's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

See this for information on [currency data type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/field_types.htm#i1435537)

> For organizations that have the **multicurrency option enabled**, the
> **CurrencyIsoCode** field is defined for any object that can have currency
> fields. The CurrencyIsoCode field and currency fields are linked in a
> special way. On any specific record, the CurrencyIsoCode field defines
> the currency of that record, and thus, the values of all currency
> fields on that record will be expressed in that currency.
>
> To perform currency conversions, client applications can look up the **CurrencyIsoCode in the CurrencyType object**.

[image]